# Time data format in python

Tags: python, date

I am reading dates from csv to python in the form of 2017-01-04. I am trying to process dates like

```
from datetime import datetime       
day1 = datetime.strptime(date1, date_format)
```

where I use `date_format = "%y-%m-%d"`

However, when I process the data, I get the error:

`time data '2017-01-04' does not match format '%y-%m-%d'`

What should it be?

Comment: It's `"%Y-%m-%d"` upper-case `Y` for 4 digit years, see the [docs](https://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html#strftime-and-strptime-behavior)

Answer (score 4):

> Y - Year with century as a decimal number.
>
> y - Year without century as a zero-padded decimal number.

Therefore, you should use Upper Y.

For more information about the formats, you can see it all in [here](http://strftime.org/)

Answer (score 0):

Something like :

```
from datetime import datetime
day1 = datetime.utcnow().strptime('2017-01-04', '%Y-%m-%d')
```

Answer (score 0):

> You can run it-This code run successfully and print-2017-01-04 00:00:00

```
     from datetime import datetime
     day1 = datetime.utcnow().strptime('2017-01-04', '%Y-%m-%d')
     print(day1)
```